# Will a delegate run while I am sitting on Console.ReadLine()?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I am very very new to delegates!

I have an AsyncCallback delegate which runs a method.

This method periodically writes text to the console (Console.WriteLine("FooBar"))

This delegate is kicked off from my Main method and I need to find a way to keep this Main method open while the delegate runs. Otherwise, the program starts, kicks off the delegate and closes again so I am using Console.Readline.

Will this work? Will my program be able to both sit at Console.ReadLine while my delegate periodically writes text to the console with Console.WriteLine or am I an idiot? My code is below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NetworkStream myNetworkStream;
    Socket socket;
    IPEndPoint maxPort = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.x"), xxxx);

    socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
    socket.Connect(maxPort);

    myNetworkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int offset = 0;
    int count = 1024;

    string loginString = "FOOBARR";
    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

    myNetworkStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, new AsyncCallback(OnBeginRead), myNetworkStream);
    myNetworkStream.Write(encoder.GetBytes(loginString), 0, encoder.GetByteCount(loginString));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void OnBeginRead(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    NetworkStream ns = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;
    int bufferSize = 2014;
    byte[] received = new byte[bufferSize];
    string result = String.Empty;

    ns.EndRead(ar);

    int read;

    while (true)
    {
        if (ns.DataAvailable)
        {
            read = ns.Read(received, 0, bufferSize);
            result += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
            received = new byte[bufferSize];

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if I call 'myNetworkStream.BeginRead' multiple times with different parameters, will a different version of my 'OnBeginRead' method start each time on a seperate thread on the processor or will the method that was running stop and be replaced by the more recent one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will my program be able to both sit at Console.ReadLine while my delegate periodically writes >text to the console with Console.WriteLine?

Short answer: Yes

> if I call 'myNetworkStream.BeginRead' multiple times with different
>   parameters will a different version of my 'OnBeginRead' method start
>   each time on a seperate thread on the processor or will the method
>   that was running stop and be replace by the more recent one

MSDN says this about calling BeginRead multiple times

> Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an
>   instance of the NetworkStream class without the need for
>   synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write
>   operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will
>   be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no
>   synchronization is required.

Which implies that you shouldn't call `BeginRead` from multiple threads. This will lead to unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Should work just fine. I've done similar things dozens of times. No worries!